# How to pass the Datetime value as parameter to a stored function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I created a function in SQL SERVER that takes in parameter a datetime value, and when I tried to execute it, I didn't know how to pass a Datetime value as parameter to this function, I got this error : Failed to convert date and / or time from a string.

this is the code of my function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[nb_pieces_produites] (@dateInsertion datetime)
returns decimal(4,0)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @year decimal(4,0), @month decimal(2,0), @day decimal(2,0) ,@hour 
decimal(2,0), @nbPiecesProduites decimal(4,0)

set @year = (select DATEPART(yyyy, @dateInsertion))
set @month = (select DATEPART(mm, @dateInsertion))
set @day = (select DATEPART(dd, @dateInsertion))
set @hour = (select DATEPART(hh, @dateInsertion))

set @nbPiecesProduites = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Num_Serie) FROM [dbo].
[dbo_Test] WHERE @dateInsertion BETWEEN '@year-@month-@day @hour:00:00' AND 
'@year-@month-@day @hour:59:59')

return @nbPiecesProduites
END
```

and this is my query :

```
select [dbo].[nb_pieces_produites]('2017-06-19 11:38:52')
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Remove all of your DATEPART code. And avoid using `BETWEEN` with dates because it's an inclusive range, not an inclusive-exclusive range.

Comment: Instead use `WHERE yourDateColumn >= @dateInsertion AND yourDateColumn < DATEADD( day, 1, @dateInsertion )`

Comment: Why are you comparing parameter `@dateInsertion` to datetime which is obtained from this parameter? This will be alway true...

Comment: If I remove the DATEPART from the code, how can i extract the hours and the seconds from the date ?

Comment: The string it's (probably) failing to convert is `'@year-@month-@day @hour:00:00'`. It doesn't do any form of string interpolation. It won't be replacing e.g. `@year` with the content of the `@year` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't spend lots of time fiddling around with strings - try to keep your data as `datetime` data throughout.

To round a datetime down to the previous hour boundary, use a `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` pair:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[nb_pieces_produites] (@dateInsertion datetime)
returns decimal(4,0)
AS
BEGIN

set @nbPiecesProduites = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Num_Serie) FROM [dbo].
[dbo_Test] WHERE
date_column_from_table >= DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,@dateInsertion),0)
   AND
date_column_from_table < DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,@dateInsertion)+1,0)
)

return @nbPiecesProduites
END
```

And, just to be safe, call it like this:

```
select [dbo].[nb_pieces_produites]('2017-06-19T11:38:52')
```

(Occasionally, under some settings, SQL Server will interpret nnnn-nn-nn as yyyy-dd-mm rather than yyyy-mm-dd, if it's followed by a *space* and then a time, rather than using `T` as the separator)

Comment: It is a good technique to round down the datetime to hour/minute using `dateadd`/`datediff`

Comment: @Eric - it depends how used you are to seeing it. I use it quite frequently because the same general pattern can be used in all kinds of ways - rounding to any datetime element (although for seconds and millis, some adjustment of the constant may be required), obtaining e.g. "the last day of the previous month", etc.

Answer (score 1):

it's error because your function expect dateTime value, but when you called it  you passing string not dateTime

change your query into :

```
select [dbo].[nb_pieces_produites](getDate())
```

Comment: same problem : Failed to convert date and / or time from a string.

Comment: @AnesGongi - that's because it's the strings inside your function that cannot be converted to datetimes, not (specifically) how you're calling the function.

Comment: @Gusti : I added the letter T beween the date and the time and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[nb_pieces_produites] (@dateInsertion datetime)
RETURNS decimal(4,0)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Num_Serie) 
        FROM dbo.dbo_Test 
        WHERE 
            -- Use the date part to compare
            CONVERT(date, [datetimecolumn]) = CONVERT(date, @dateInsertion) 
            -- Then compare with hour
            AND DATEPART(HOUR, [datetimecolumn]) = DATEPART(HOUR, @dateInsertion)
    )
END
```

Comment: Close but the OPs code goes to the hour, not the day.